# How can you check if a series$ ∑_1^{\infty} x^{2}e^{−nx}$ is convergent when $ x \in [0,+∞)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

How can you check if a series $$∑_1^{\infty} x^2e^{−nx}$$ is convergent when $x$ belongs to $[0,∞)$ step by step? Can D'Alembert's theorem be used? Could someone write it step by step?

Comment: What have you tried?  For example, can you bound it with an intergrable curve?

Comment: To determine if a series converges, I tried using a quotient test. This test states that if the absolute value of the quotient of consecutive terms in a series is less than 1, then the series converges.

To apply the quotient test to a given series, I first tried to find the ratio of consecutive terms. In this case "n" the term of the series appears to be: x^2e^−nx and "(n+1)" the term is x^2e^−(n+1)x. So the ratio of consecutive terms is:

x^2e^−nx / x^2e^−(n+1)x = e^(−(n+1)x + nx) = e^−x

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? Unfortunately, I am not an experienced mathematician and I have quite a long break in counting such tasks.

Comment: If you pull out $x^{2}$ you get a geometric series.

Comment: From the notation, it seemed to me that this series is a power series, but due to my inexperience, I may be wrong.

Comment: $∑_1^{\infty} x^2e^{−nx}= x^2∑_1^{\infty} ( \frac{1}{e^x})^n.$  Geometric series !

Answer (score 2):

For $x=0$ we have $\sum _{k=1}^N  x^2 e^{-kx} = 0$ for every $N$, so the series converges (to $0$). Otherwise, as pointed out in the comments, we have
$$ \sum x^2 e^{-nx} = x^2 \sum e^{-nx} = x^2 \sum \left ( e^{-x} \right )^n. $$
This series converges if and only if the geometric series $\sum (e^{-x})^n$ converges. This occurs if and only if $e^{-x}< 1$ (i.e $x>0$).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm quite behind on this math, I need to learn more. Thank you.

Comment: @AghorClee Do you know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n =\frac{1}{1-a}$ if $-1<a<1$?

Comment: Yes. The formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series is ∑n=0^∞ a^n = 1 / (1 - a) for any value of a that satisfies -1 < a < 1. If I'm not mistaken of course.

Comment: @AghorClee Take $a=e^{-x}$, $x>0$.